# How to rank objects by property?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to rank a collection of objects by property value. Basically every player object has a score property that should be ranked from highest to lowest. Example:

```
var players = {
    player1: {
        nickname: "Bob",
        score: 100
    },
    player2: {
        nickname: "Amy",
        score: 200
    },
    player3: {
        nickname: "Grant",
        score: 300
    },
    player4: {
        nickname: "Steve",
        score: 200
    },
    player5: {
        nickname: "Joe",
        score: 500
    }
};
```

Ranking these objects by score should produce the following:

```
{
    player1: {
        nickname: "Bob",
        score: 100,
        rank: 4
    },
    player2: {
        nickname: "Amy",
        score: 200,
        rank: 3
    },
    player3: {
        nickname: "Grant",
        score: 300,
        rank: 2
    },
    player4: {
        nickname: "Steve",
        score: 200,
        rank: 3
    },
    player5: {
        nickname: "Joe",
        score: 500,
        rank: 1
    }
}
```

The important part is that objects with the same score should have equal rank.

Here's as far as I got:

```
var array = [];

for (var key in players) {
    array.push(players[key]);

}

array.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.score - b.score;
});

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i].rank = i + 1;
}
```

That will assign a "rank" property to each object in order of their score, but how could you give tied objects the same rank number?

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2khtnjxw/2/)

Comment: Within the last for loop, compare the current item's score to the previous one and don't increment the rank variable if scores are equal. Which would also mean an extra variable for current rank rather than just using the loop index like you do currently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2khtnjxw/1/

```
// change sort function
array.sort(function(a, b){
    return b.score - a.score;
});

var rank = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  // increase rank only if current score less than previous
  if (i > 0 && array[i].score < array[i - 1].score) {
    rank++;
  }
    array[i].rank = rank;
}

// result: 
[  
   {  
      "nickname":"Joe",
      "score":500,
      "rank":1
   },
   {  
      "nickname":"Grant",
      "score":300,
      "rank":2
   },
   {  
      "nickname":"Amy",
      "score":200,
      "rank":3
   },
   {  
      "nickname":"Steve",
      "score":200,
      "rank":3
   },
   {  
      "nickname":"Bob",
      "score":100,
      "rank":4
   }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are fortunate enough to be able to take advantage of some new ES6 methods, you can create a Set of scores:

```
var scores = new Set(Object.keys(players).map(function (key) {
  return players[key].score;
}));
// > Set {100, 200, 300, 500}
```

Then convert it into an Array and order it:

```
var ordered_scores = Array.from(scores).sort(function(a, b) {
  return b - a;
});
// > [500, 300, 200, 100]
```

And then simply update your players in-place:

```
Object.keys(players).forEach(function (key) {
  var player = players[key];
  player.rank = ordered_scores.indexOf(player.score) + 1;
});
```

```js
var players = {
    player1: {
        nickname: "Bob",
        score: 100
    },
    player2: {
        nickname: "Amy",
        score: 200
    },
    player3: {
        nickname: "Grant",
        score: 300
    },
    player4: {
        nickname: "Steve",
        score: 200
    },
    player5: {
        nickname: "Joe",
        score: 500
    }
};

var scores = new Set(Object.keys(players).map(function (key) {
  return players[key].score;
}));

var ordered_scores = Array.from(scores).sort(function(a, b) {
  return b - a;
});

Object.keys(players).forEach(function (key) {
  var player = players[key];
  player.rank = ordered_scores.indexOf(player.score) + 1;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(players, null, 2) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning rank property to the key array, instead you need to update the `players` object and also check the adjacent  values are equal for make the same rank. Also you are sorting function should be change in order  to sort in descending, as per your code it's sort in ascending.

```js
var players = {
  player1: {
    nickname: "Bob",
    score: 100
  },
  player2: {
    nickname: "Amy",
    score: 200
  },
  player3: {
    nickname: "Grant",
    score: 300
  },
  player4: {
    nickname: "Steve",
    score: 200
  },
  player5: {
    nickname: "Joe",
    score: 500
  }
};

// get keys from object
var arr = Object.keys(players);
// sort keys array based on score value
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return players[b].score - players[a].score;
});
// iterate key array and assign rank value to object
for (var i = 0, rank = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  // assign rank value
  players[arr[i]].rank = rank;
  // increment rank only if score value is changed
  if (players[arr[i + 1]] && players[arr[i]].score != players[arr[i + 1]].score)
    rank++;
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(players, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we can make a custom method for ranking an array of objects:

```
//  arr.rank()
Array.prototype.rank = function(compare, consecutiveRanks=true, rankPropertyName='rank'){

  const sorted = this
      .slice()            // copy the array
      .sort(compare);     // sort array of objects (in place)
    
  let current;            // object keeping the current rank

  //  Note：
  // - indices (keys) of array.entries() are "integer-based"
  // - indices (keys) of Object.entries(array) are "string-based"❗❗❗
  for(const [i, obj] of sorted.entries()){  

    // if not the same, generate new rank
    if (!current || compare(current, obj) !== 0) {
      obj[rankPropertyName] = (
          !consecutiveRanks ? i + 1 :        // ranks may have "gaps"
          !current          ?     1 :        // first rank
          current[rankPropertyName] + 1      // consecutive ranks
      );
      current = obj;
    }
        
    // if the same, use the current rank.
    else {
      obj[rankPropertyName] = current[rankPropertyName];
    }

  }

  return sorted;
};
```

use cases:

```
const players = [
    { nickname: "Bob"  , score: 100 },
    { nickname: "Amy"  , score: 200 },
    { nickname: "Grant", score: 300 },
    { nickname: "Steve", score: 200 },
    { nickname: "Joe"  , score: 500 },
];

console.log(players.rank((a,b) => b.score - a.score));
// [
//   { nickname: 'Joe'  , score: 500, rank: 1 },
//   { nickname: 'Grant', score: 300, rank: 2 },
//   { nickname: 'Amy'  , score: 200, rank: 3 },
//   { nickname: 'Steve', score: 200, rank: 3 },
//   { nickname: 'Bob'  , score: 100, rank: 4 }    // ⭐️ consecutive rank
// ]

console.log(players.rank((a,b) => b.score - a.score, false));
// [
//   { nickname: 'Joe'  , score: 500, rank: 1 },
//   { nickname: 'Grant', score: 300, rank: 2 },
//   { nickname: 'Amy'  , score: 200, rank: 3 },
//   { nickname: 'Steve', score: 200, rank: 3 },
//   { nickname: 'Bob'  , score: 100, rank: 5 }    // ⭐️ rank 4 is skipped.
// ]

console.log(players);
// [
//   { nickname: 'Bob'  , score: 100, rank: 5 },    // in original order
//   { nickname: 'Amy'  , score: 200, rank: 3 },
//   { nickname: 'Grant', score: 300, rank: 2 },
//   { nickname: 'Steve', score: 200, rank: 3 },
//   { nickname: 'Joe'  , score: 500, rank: 1 }
// ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @hamms for the idea.

I made typescript (generic) implementation:

```
export function getRanks<T>(
  items: T[],
  getId: (item: T) => string,
  getScore: (item: T) => number,
): Map<string, number> {
  const itemScoresMap = items.reduce(
    (r, x) => r.set(getId(x), getScore(x)),
    new Map(),
  )

  const uniqueScores = new Set(itemScoresMap.values())
  const orderedScores = Array.from(uniqueScores).sort((a, b) => b - a)

  return items
    .map(x => {
      const id = getId(x)
      const score = itemScoresMap.get(id)

      return {
        id,
        rank: orderedScores.indexOf(score) + 1,
      }
    })
    .reduce((r, x) => r.set(x.id, x.rank), new Map())
}
```